Kotlin Serializable Any item
I encountered a problem with data serialization. The REST API is not mine and I can't change it. For a certain request I receive a Object:
data class State(
   val instance: String,
   val value: Any
)

Various types of data can come as the value parameter of an object, such as Boolean, String, Int, Float and even Object, for exemple:
"state": {
   "instance": "rgb",
   "value": 13910520    
}
// OR
"state": {
   "instance": "hsv",
   "value": {
      "h": 255,
      "s": 100,
      "v": 50
   }
}

In this case, the value type depends on instance (instance is always a String type). With the help of this answer, I was more or less able to understand the various types, but I did not understand how I should work if receive an Object in response.
@Serializable(with = StateSerializer::class)
data class StateObject(
    val instance: String,
    val value: Any
)
object StateSerializer : KSerializer<StateObject> {
    private val dataTypeSerializers: Map<String, KSerializer<Any>> =
        mapOf(
            "..." to serialDescriptor<Boolean>(),
            "..." to serialDescriptor<String>(),
            "..." to serialDescriptor<Int>()
        ).mapValues { (_, v) -> v as KSerializer<Any> }

    private fun getValueSerializer(instance: String): KSerializer<Any> =
        dataTypeSerializers[instance] ?: throw SerializationException()

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor("StateObject") {
        element("instance", serialDescriptor<String>())
        element("value", buildClassSerialDescriptor("Any"))
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): StateObject = decoder.decodeStructure(
        descriptor) {
        if (decodeSequentially()) {
            val instance = decodeStringElement(descriptor, 0)
            val value = decodeSerializableElement(
                descriptor,
                1,
                getValueSerializer(instance)
            )
            StateObject(instance, value)
        } else {
            require(decodeElementIndex(descriptor) == 0) {  }
            val instance = decodeStringElement(descriptor, 0)
            val value = when (val index = decodeElementIndex(descriptor)) {
                1 -> decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, 1, getValueSerializer(instance))
                CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE -> throw SerializationException("value field is missing")
                else -> error("Unexpected index: $index")
            }
            StateObject(instance, value)
        }
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: StateObject) {
        encoder.encodeStructure(descriptor) {
            encodeStringElement(descriptor, 0, value.instance)
            encodeSerializableElement(
                descriptor,
                1,
                getValueSerializer(value.instance),
                value.value
            )
        }
    }
}


That instance field looks like your class discriminator.
In that case you can use it for built in polymophic handling without the need for writing custom serializer:
    @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
    @JsonClassDiscriminator("instance")
    @Serializable
    sealed class State {
        abstract val value: Any

        @Serializable
        @SerialName("rgb")
        data class RGB(override val value: Int) : State()

        @Serializable
        @SerialName("hsv")
        data class HSV(override val value: HSValues) : State()

        // declare all possible types
    }


This is a better answer than mine and should be the accepted one, it's much moe concise.

Interesting. I think this method will not work if, for example, for different instance values ​​I will receive different types of the value parameter. In this case, I think there will be a large amount of code duplication. "rgb", "temperature_k" -> State.SomeInt.serializer()

The (sealed) class type is what allows you to discern actual meaning of value since there's no actual "instance" field. Maybe there's some overhead but mapping API endpoints to code is almost always painful.

The easiest way is probably to avoid using Any in the first place. You may not be able to change the REST API, but you can change your data class. Instead of using only one data class with an Any value you should create separate data classes for each specific type of instance:
sealed interface State {
    val instance: String
    val value: Any

    @Serializable
    data class RGB(
        override val instance: String,
        override val value: Int,
    ) : State

    @Serializable
    data class HSV(
        override val instance: String,
        override val value: HSVValues,
    ) : State
}

With HSVValues being this:
@Serializable
data class HSVValues(
    val h: Int,
    val s: Int,
    val v: Int,
)

Just add the remaining cases to the interface. A String State and a Boolean State could look like this:
@Serializable
data class SomeString(
    override val instance: String,
    override val value: String,
) : State

@Serializable
data class SomeBoolean(
    override val instance: String,
    override val value: Boolean,
) : State

Now you can use a simple polymorphic serializer like this:
object StateSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<State>(State::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<State> {
        return when (element.jsonObject["instance"]?.jsonPrimitive?.content) {
            "rgb" -> State.RGB.serializer()
            "hsv" -> State.HSV.serializer()
            "..." -> State.SomeString.serializer()
            "..." -> State.SomeBoolean.serializer()
            else -> throw SerializationException("Unknown instance ${element.jsonObject["instance"]}")
        }
    }
}

Since the types are now well defined you only need the deserialization part, the serialization works out-of-the-box.
Then annotate the interface with the serializer and you are all set:
@Serializable(with = StateSerializer::class)
sealed interface State {
    ...
}

Using dedicated data classes for each type of instance is not just easier to (de)serialize, it is also easier for your remaining code to work with because you do not have to handle some unknown Any type at runtime. Instead you can use the proper type that is already available at compile time.

It seems to me that we need to replace DeserializationStrategy<State> with KSerializer<out State>. Or I'm wrong?

The function we overwrite is protected abstract fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<T> (note the return type). KSerializer is more general than that because it also implements a SerializationStrategy (which we don't need here). Both will work, but DeserializationStrategy is more precise.
